# Is this a correct database model for a Tution Academy?

Tags: php, database, model, diagram

Can anyone help me if this Database model is correct for a tuition class.
Academy has many grades, each grades have many subjects. A subject can have more than one teacher. A teacher can teach more than one grade. In a fee paid by a student for a subject, A commission goes to that particular lecturer and the rest comes to the academy.
Hope to get some response thank you.

[Click to view the Diagram/ Model I propose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEjYm.png)

Comment: I would have thought there should be a link between the student table and one of the grade tables.

Comment: I'll look into that Mr. Ren, Thank you very much and I really appreciate this.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be correct, but you should rename your columns and tables, it's hard to understand for others - I'm not sure what is `tbl_alpha`

http://www.vertabelo.com/blog/technical-articles/naming-conventions-in-database-modeling

https://launchbylunch.com/posts/2014/Feb/16/sql-naming-conventions/

etc.

Comment: tbl_alpha is the Administration, the commissions of the organization will be added to that table, thought it might help to calculate profits and margins for the staffs and the organization.